# 画面のドキュメントの範囲へのドロップを禁止にする

Tags: javascript, html5

画面のドキュメントの範囲へのドロップのみを禁止にする方法を調査していますが、なかなか答えが出せません。

javascript内で

```
$(function () {
        $(document).on('drop', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

このような実装をしてみたのですが、上手くいきませんでした。分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

参考: [Cancelling HTML5 drag and drop events in web browsers](http://www.ioscorner.com/2014/07/programmatically-enable-kiosk-mode-in.html)

`dragover`を追加するとキャンセルできるようです。Chromeで確認しました。

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。